# How to change AD password from MAC OS Sierra

Tags: macos, homebrew, smb

I'm trying to change my Windows AD from my Mac password by doing:

```
diego$ smbpasswd -U username -r DOMAIN_CONTROLLER_IP
-bash: smbpasswd: command not found
```

As the command was not found I tried to install samba with homebrew without any luck:

```
diego$ brew install samba
Updating Homebrew...
==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
Updated 1 tap (homebrew/cask).
No changes to formulae.

Error: No available formula with the name "samba" 
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Warning: homebrew/core is shallow clone. To get complete history run:
git -C "$(brew --repo homebrew/core)" fetch --unshallow

Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching taps...
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
```

Do you why I can't install samba with brew ? Is there any other command / tool that I can use to change my AD password from Mac Os Sierra ?

Comment: [smbpasswd command not found on MacOS High Sierra](https://superuser.com/questions/1333536/smbpasswd-command-not-found-on-macos-high-sierra). See the answer concerning `kpasswd`. There's a man page.

Comment: Why can't you use the Change Password button in Sys Prefs - Users and Groups?

Comment: @Hefewe1zen This is an Active Directory account, not a local account on the macOS. It won't work.

Comment: @CyberMew You can def change AD passwords that way as well, YMMV depending on how your domain / security is set up

Comment: @Hefewe1zen you're right, but I think the macOS has to first be binded to a AD Domain before they are linked.